# Outer product of vector with self versus inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, outer-product

I have a real-valued column vector $v$ and the following equation
$$
\frac{v v^T}{1+\alpha v^T v}
$$
with $\alpha>0$, and I'm trying to find an upper limit not including $v$.

I have found that the following holds for a 2-element vector $v$:
\begin{align}
\frac{v v^T}{1+\alpha v^T v} &\leq \frac{\lambda_{max}(v v^T)}{1+\alpha v^T v} I\\
&= \frac{v^T v}{1+\alpha v^T v} I\\
&\leq \frac{1}{\alpha} I
\end{align}
Since the (only non-zero) eigenvalue of the outer product of $v$ is its own inner product, at least for a two-element vector.

Two questions:

- Does the result generalize to any number of elements in $v$?
- Does there exist a less conservative upper limit not involving $v$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, yes: the spectrum of the matrix $v v^T$ is $\{ v^T v \}$ (euclidean norm). That's because it is a rank-one matrix, so has at most one eigenvalue; and an eigenvector is given by $v$.

Second, consider the function $t \mapsto \frac{t}{1 + \alpha t} = \frac1\alpha \frac{t \alpha}{1 + t \alpha}$. The last fraction is bounded by $1$ for $t \to \infty$. So, I don't think you can bound the function by something not involving $t$.